# Wrap long href in div with a floated image

Tags: css

I am trying to wrap text around a floated image with a long href as part of the text.

I can get the text to wrap no problems, but when I add a long link (whos width exceeds that of the floated image), the link is forced below the floated image.

So this:

```
 __________________________
| text text text   _____   |
| text text text  |     |  |
| text text text  |_____|  |
| text text text           |
| text text text text text |
| text text.               |
|__________________________|
```

becomes this:

```
 __________________________
| text text text   _____   |
| text text text  |     |  |
| text text       |_____|  |
|                          |
| <this is the link> text  |
| text text text text text |
| text.                    |
|__________________________|
```

Where I would like this:

```
 __________________________
| text text text   _____   |
| text text text  |     |  |
| text text <this |_____|  |
| is the link>             |
| text text text text text |
| text text.               |
|__________________________|
```

I have tried "word-break: break-all;" but of course, this breaks every line, often mid word.

I have considered using JavaScript to insert "<wbr />" tags after the protocol, domain, extension, and any uri params in the text portion of the "a" tag, but was hoping for a CSS solution, if one exists.

Here is a JSFiddle of the conundrum http://jsfiddle.net/vBbau/2/.

Anyone know a more elegant solution to this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a "link" problem. This is because of the inner html of the  link is considered as one big word with no space. So the big word must fit without breaking itself.

If you try a big word as plain text outside the link, it will break the floating too.

Apply the break-all only to the link, so it will succeed:

```
.container .content a{
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qR46N/1/

And if your link is the first text, maybe a trick like this could work :

JSfiddles : http://jsfiddle.net/qR46N/3/

Comment: This is almost perfect. I don't know why I didn't think of it myself! 
  
I am getting some odd results though. If the content begins with a 'a' tag (with no content or spaces proceeding it), the break-all is not doing anything. Inserting any spaces prior to the tag does not help either. Inserting some _text_ and a space prior to the 'a' tag _does_ work.  
  
I am having to insert the string 'Goto ' at the beginning of the container if the content begins with a 'a' tag for this solution to work consistently, which I would rather not have to do :/
  
Any thoughts? (Chrome 28.0.1500.72 m).

Comment: indeed, it's a weird thing... I have updated with a home made tricks. Not a very smart one, but it does the job !

Comment: The break-corrector idea worked well, thanks for that ;) I have implemented a similar approach and all is looking good.

Answer (score 0):

Create an another class for `<a>` and apply the following css

```
.container .content a{
        display: inline-block; 
         max-width: 130px; 
         vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vBbau/4/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in this scenario the containers are responsive, therefore forcing any widths would end up looking odd.